# How to join multiple tables in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an issue when trying to join multiple tables.

I try joining:

`Table A` > `Table B`

`Table A` > `Table C`

`Table A` > `Table D`

`Table D` > `Table F`

`Table D` > `Table G`

When I run the code, it shows the following error:

> Error No Records Returned

I want just Join Table for show all Data.

```
Sub ConnectSql()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim Sheet As String
    Dim NW As String
    Dim intFieldIndex As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim L As Integer
    Dim SQL As String
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
        "Data Source=SQLServer;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=Test"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    conn.Open sConnString
    SQL = "SELECT TABLE A.ID,TABLE A.Name,TABLE B.Des," & _
        "TABLE D.Comcode,TABLE D.Comdes,TABLE C.Type,TABLE C.TypeDes " & _
        "FROM((TABLE A INNER JOIN TABLE B ON TABLE A.ID = TABLE B.ID) " & _
        "INNER JOIN TABLE D ON TABLE A.COMCODE = TABLE D.COMCODE)" & _
        "INNER JOIN TABLE C ON TABLE A.TYPE = TABLE C.TYPE"
    Set rs = conn.Execute(SQL)
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add( _
    After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
             For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
             Next
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably should provide some sample data. But basically you are using inner joins, unless the join conditions specified in your inner joins have matching values as per specified by the join conditions, you won't get any data back. For example, you say `TABLE A INNER JOIN TABLE B ON TABLE A.ID = TABLE B.ID` (which by the way is not valid syntax, you shouldn't have the word "TABLE" in your join conditions), you will only get data back if the ID values in A = the ID values in B (and similarly for tables D and C).